Android - Epson ePos SDK - Cannot Print on Epson TM-T88VI printer
I cannot seem to be able to print on the Epson TM-T88VI printer.
I have followed the tutorial in the docs. I can find a printer with the ePos Finder class and it gets populated in the mList variable. I can build using the epos builder but
While debugging

the exception has been thrown on the line of printer.openPrinter(firstDevice.deviceType,firstDevice.ipAddress,Print.TRUE,10,10)
I get an error status of ERR_PARAM but all the paramaters are correct and I've tried changing paramaters around but still nothing works :(
When I go inside the method it is part of the Epson ePos SDK and it throws on the eposOpenPrinter() line.
I have attached the stack trace below the code below.

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), BatteryStatusChangeEventListener, StatusChangeEventListener{
        private var mList: Array<DeviceInfo>? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                initializePrinter()
    }

private fun initializePrinter() {
    try {
        Finder.start(baseContext, DevType.TCP, "192.168.0.34")
        while (mList == null || mList?.size == 0) {
            mList = Finder.getDeviceInfoList(FilterOption.PARAM_DEFAULT)
        }
        Finder.stop()
        if (!mList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val builder = Builder("TM-T88VI", Builder.MODEL_ANK)

            builder.apply {
                addTextLang(Builder.LANG_EN)
                addTextSmooth(Builder.TRUE)
                addTextFont(Builder.FONT_A)
                addTextSize(3, 3)
                addText("It \t")
                addText("Finally Works\n")
                addCut(Builder.CUT_FEED)
            }

            val printer = Print()
            val status = intArrayOf(0)
            //wifi/ethernet
            val firstDevice = mList!!.first()


            printer.openPrinter(
                firstDevice.deviceType,
                firstDevice.ipAddress,
                Print.TRUE,
                10,
                10
            )
            printer.sendData(builder, 10_000, status)

            if ((status[0] and Print.ST_PRINT_SUCCESS) == Print.ST_PRINT_SUCCESS) {
                builder.clearCommandBuffer()
            }

            printer.closePrinter()
        }
    } catch (e: EposException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

override fun onBatteryStatusChangeEvent(p0: String?, p1: Int) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun onStatusChangeEvent(p0: String?, p1: Int) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

}
'''
The stack trace is
2024-04-30 15:16:52.524 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at com.epson.eposprint.Print.openPrinter(Print.java:467)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.524 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at com.example.printertest.MainActivity.initializePrinter(MainActivity.kt:47)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.524 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at com.example.printertest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.524 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8595)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.525 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8573)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.525 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1456)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.525 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3764)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.525 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.525 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.525 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.526 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.527 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.528 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.528 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.528 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.528 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.528 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.529 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
2024-04-30 15:16:52.529 15851-15851 System.err              com.example.printertest              W      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 

